# Count how much matches in last 10 rows

Tags: php, mysql

I need help to implement how much status=1 I have in last 10 rows from results?

If its there 3 status in last 10 rows, i need to got 3 output.

```
SELECT * FROM results WHERE $position='$text' and make='$make' and status='1'
```

Comment: How do you determine what is "last?"

Comment: `SELECT * FROM results WHERE ... id > (SELECT max(id) - 10 FROM results) AS x`? assuming a serial id column.

Comment: all results has auto increment id
so last 10 id witch has status 1 i try that, but always i got 10 output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a subquery to get the last 10 rows, and then count how many have `status = 1` in that subset.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (SELECT status
      FROM results
      WHERE $position = '$text' AND make = '$make'
      ORDER BY id DESC
      LIMIT 10) AS last10
WHERE status = '1'
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5938a/1)

Comment: I always got result 1. But in last 10 rows i have 6 matches

Comment: You're using `$row['count'']` to get the count, not `mysql_num_rows()`, right?